# integer != float 100 != 100.00

Tags: php, integer

I have a problem with integer and float in PHP :/
My Code:

```
$dif =floatval($sum)-floatval($this->row_array[$row][$col]);  
echo $dif;
```

`$sum` is 100
`$this->row_array[$row][$col]` is 100.00
but `$dif` is -1.4210854715202E-14!
Do you have any idea why `$dif` isn't 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating point numbers are represented as a binary approximation of a decimal number (see this [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) for an in-depth explanation how they are stored). As you can see in your example they are "reasonably close" but not an exact representation of said decimal number. Thus, if you then compare it against an integer - which is a precise representation of the number it contains - you can get small differences, as you have seen.

To compare floating point numbers, the correct technique is usually to add a "tolerance" to the comparison - instead of comparing two numbers precisely, you check if one falls within a small interval of the other. How small an interval depends on how large or small the number is.

Comment: You only have to round the floating point value if you want to round before comparison.